# Import localizable.strings into XIB

Tags: xcode, cocoa, interface-builder, xib, ibtool

I am currently refactoring an Xcode project for Interface Builder and I am looking for a way to import strings in existing localizable.strings files into newly-created XIB files that use the same strings.

I have tried Xcode’s XLIFF export/import function, but it will only import the strings that were exported from the XIB files, and `ibtool`’s `--import-strings-file` command won’t accept localizable.strings as input, only previously exported strings files that originated from a XIB file already.

Is there anything I can use, without having to do everything manually?

Answer (score 0):

1. Select your Xib file, then select `localize...` under the `Localization` option.
   [localize](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sl9Xk.jpg)
2. Select the language you want to internationalize, and click `Localize`.
3. You can see Internationalization file has been generated.
   [Success](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JwfAh.jpg)

Comment: This will create an empty strings file. What I want is to import already translated strings into this file, without having to do it manually or writing a script.